# House generator with 4 prong female end

Tags: generator

Our home is wired with a female end for a generator. All generators have female ends for plugging things in.  Can you get a male-male adaptor to connect the generator to the house?  If not what is the solution?

Comment: Can you trace the quite improper generator "connection" back to the panel it connects to?

Comment: Pictures would be helpful for spotting other errors, possibly. You can [edit] to add those.

Answer (score 6):

That is an improper connector for a "suicide cord" - remove it and replace it with a proper "inlet." Which is a "male connector you mount on the wall."

Never heard of the place that had a usable picture of one, and no endorsement is implied. This one hapens to be "twist-lock" (L prefix) style. The pictures I could find of straight-blade styles were from sites that the images would not copy correctly from. This is an L14-30P inlet - 14-30P inlets, 14-50P inlets and (twist locking) CS6375 inlets are all possibilities. 30 is 30 Amperes, 50 is 50 Amperes

[image: image of a L14-30L from gordon electric supply]

A suicide cord is so-called becasue it has exposed energized prongs.

**The fact that your generator input is wired for a suicide cord strongly suggests that it may have other issues (such as lack of a proper interlock) and should be completely reviewed for safety and code-compliance.** Those can and do kill people.

Comment: Note that there is no L14-50 anything, CS6375 type connectors are used instead

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Thanks, corrected.

Comment: Note that in a pinch, you can achieve 95% of the safety with a "hillbilly inlet"...   using a junction box and a 4-wire dryer or range cord (the kind with a plug).  Stop by an electrical supply house to get the correct *strain relief* for the cord (and a junction box that will fit that strain relief, and the cord while you're at it).  That will give you the male connector needed to not be *immediately lethal*, although it's still a code violation because of risk of damage to the cord, and the weather will quickly destroy it.

Comment: I know someone with a house generator with a worse rigup. If you didn't go turn off all of the breakers before plugging it in, bad things happened. It was intended to power one of the two kitchen 120 circuits (the one the fridge happened to be on) but you suicide-cord plugged it into a wall.

Comment: I'm not going to justify the suicide plug rigup; but it appears because it can be built from common (cheap) parts. The interlock is expensive in comparison.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica: I'm drawing blank on Hillbilly inlet.

Comment: Lack of an interlock can be very expensive. It is not at all unusual for power company workers to investigate running generators when they are restoring power. Those without an interlock may find that their power is disconnected, rather than being restored. A simple manual interlock is an inexpensive hunk of metal designed for your panel, and a circuit breaker, connected to an inlet, configured so the breaker can't be on if the main breaker is on. Fancy autoswitching is not a requirement, but safety that does not depend on "remembering not to do this without doing that" is.

Comment: @Joshua "interlock" and "suicide cord" are orthogonal (separate issues unrelated).  You don't have to buy a $400 transfer switch,  most modern panels have OEM interlocks for $27-70.  A person can have a proper interlock and still run a suicide cord - I'd rather see that combo than the other, as suicide is less bad than murder of innocent linemen.   Proper inlets can also be expensive but like I say, 4-prong dryer cord and you're up for the season.